# Quorum: Can't Connect To Nodes From External Sources

Tags: web3js, nodes, quorum

I have a Quorum (7nodes example) network up and successfully running. I can connect to any geth node using the following:

```
geth attach ipc:qdata/dd1/geth.ipc
```

I can also see that the ports opened in the startup script start.sh are listening:

```
tcp6    0   0 :::21000         :::*        LISTEN
```

I can see that a provider has been set:

```
> web3.providers
{
  host: "http://devserver01:21000",
  HttpProvider: function(host),
  IpcProvider: function(path, net)
}
```

However:

```
> web3.currentProvider.isConnected()
```

returns false. I also can't reach the node using web3.min.js from a web page. The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **7 nodes example**, the correct geth ports for the nodes are **22000** to **22006**.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22000                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       28113       9235/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22001                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       28058       9236/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22002                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       29076       9237/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22003                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       29079       9238/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22004                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       28174       9239/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22005                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       28136       9240/geth
tcp6       0      0 :::22006                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       29075       9241/geth
```

Vagrant is exposing these ports to the host system by default. So, the following connection should work:

Inside vagrant or on host system: `geth attach http://localhost:22000`

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ geth attach http://localhost:22000
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.2-stable-ee498061/linux-amd64/go1.9.3
coinbase: 0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC)
 datadir: /home/vagrant/quorum-examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

You can see the NAT configuration if you look at your vagrant provider. This is virtual box:

[image: NAT configuration - virtual box]

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the ip addresses of the virtual machines. Let's suppose the ip of the virtual machine you want to connect to is 172.13.0.3. Then you can connect to the node with `geth attach http://172.13.0.3:8545`